# Вылетает программа после ввода пути к файлу в Delphi

Tags: delphi, функции, циклы, матрицы

```
program Lab2_4;
 
uses
    System.SysUtils;
 
type
    Matrix = array of array of Integer;
 
var
    MainMatrix: Matrix;
    Order: Integer;
    Path: String;
    Zero: array of Integer;
 
function IsFileCorrect(Path: String; Order: Integer): Boolean;
var
    ISize, JSize, Num: Integer;
    IsCorrect: Boolean;
    MatrixFile: TextFile;
begin
    ISize := 0;
    JSize := 0;
    IsCorrect := true;
    AssignFile(MatrixFile, Path);
    Reset(MatrixFile);
    while not(SeekEof(MatrixFile)) and IsCorrect do
    begin
        inc(ISize);
        while not(SeekEoln(MatrixFile)) and IsCorrect do
        begin
            try
                Read(MatrixFile, Num);
            except
                IsCorrect := false;
            end;
            inc(JSize);
        end;
        Readln(MatrixFile);
        if (JSize <> Order) then
            IsCorrect := false;
        JSize := 0;
    end;
    if ISize <> Order then
        IsCorrect := false;
    CloseFile(MatrixFile);
    result := IsCorrect;
end;
 
function FilePath(Order: Integer): String;
var
    Path: String;
    IsCorrect: Boolean;
begin
    repeat
        Writeln('Введите абсолютный путь к файлу ');
        Readln(Path);
        IsCorrect := false;
        if FileExists(Path) then
        begin
            if IsFileCorrect(Path, Order) then
                IsCorrect := true
            else
                Writeln('Данные в файле некорректны');
        end
        else
            Writeln('Файл не найден');
 
    until IsCorrect;
    result := Path;
end;
 
function InputOrder(): Integer;
var
    Order: Integer;
    IsCorrect: Boolean;
begin
    repeat
        Writeln('Введите порядок матрицы: ');
        IsCorrect := true;
        try
            Readln(Order)
        except
            IsCorrect := false;
            Writeln('Порядок матрицы должен быть числом')
        end;
    until IsCorrect;
    result := Order;
end;
 
function FileToMatrix(var MainMatrix:Matrix; Order: Integer; Path: String): Matrix;
var
    Ret: Matrix;
    I, J: Integer;
    MatrixFile: TextFile;
begin
    SetLength(Ret, Order, Order);
    AssignFile(MatrixFile, Path);
    Reset(MatrixFile);
    for I := 0 to Order do
    begin
        for J := 0 to Order do
        Read(MatrixFile, MainMatrix[I, J]);
        Readln(MatrixFile);
    end;
    CloseFile(MatrixFile);
    result := MainMatrix;
end;
 
function Output(): String;
var
    Patho: String;
    IsCorrect: Boolean;
begin
    IsCorrect := false;
    repeat
        Writeln('Введите директорию, в которую хотите сохранить матрицу');
        Readln(Patho);
        if DirectoryExists(Patho) then
            IsCorrect := true
        else
            Writeln('Такой директории не существует.Попробуйте ещё раз');
    until IsCorrect;
    Result := Patho;
end;
 
procedure ConditionToFile(MainMatrix: Matrix; Order: Integer; zero: array of Integer);
var
    I, J: Integer;
    OutputFile: TextFile;
    Directory: String;
begin
    Directory := Output();
    AssignFile(OutputFile, Directory + '\output.txt');
    Rewrite(OutputFile);
 
    for I := 0 to High(Zero) do
    begin
        Zero[I]:=1;
        Write(OutputFile, Zero[I]:6);
        Writeln(OutputFile);
    end;
 
    for I := 0 to High(MainMatrix) do
    begin
        for J := 0 to High(MainMatrix) do
            Write(OutputFile, MainMatrix[I, J]:6);
            Writeln(OutputFile);
    end;
 
        for I := 0 to High(Zero) do
    begin
        Zero[I]:=1;
        Write(OutputFile, Zero[I]:6);
        Writeln(OutputFile);
    end;
 
    Writeln('Матрица сохранена по указанному пути');
    CloseFile(OutputFile);
end;
 
procedure PrintMatrix(MainMatrix: Matrix);
var
    I, J: Integer;
begin
    for I := 0 to High(MainMatrix) do
    begin
        for J := 0 to High(MainMatrix) do
            Write(MainMatrix[I, J]:6);
            Writeln;
    end;
end;
 
procedure Condition(var MainMatrix: Matrix; Order: Integer; zero: array of Integer);
var
I, J:Integer;
begin
    for I := 0 to High(Zero) do
    begin
        Zero[I]:=1;
        Write(Zero[I]:6);
        Writeln;
    end;
 
    for I := 0 to High(MainMatrix) do
    begin
        for J := 0 to High(MainMatrix) do
            Write(MainMatrix[I, J]:6);
            Writeln;
    end;
 
    for I := 0 to High(Zero) do
    begin
    Zero[I]:=1;
    Write(Zero[I]:6);
    Writeln;
    end;
 
end;
 
begin
    Order := InputOrder();
    Path := FilePath(Order);
    MainMatrix := FileToMatrix(MainMatrix, Order, Path);
    PrintMatrix(MainMatrix);
    Condition(MainMatrix, Order, Zero);
    ConditionToFile(MainMatrix, Order, Zero);
    Readln;
end.
RAW Paste Data
program Lab2_4;

uses
    System.SysUtils;

type
    Matrix = array of array of Integer;

var
    MainMatrix: Matrix;
    Order: Integer;
    Path: String;
    Zero: array of Integer;

function IsFileCorrect(Path: String; Order: Integer): Boolean;
var
    ISize, JSize, Num: Integer;
    IsCorrect: Boolean;
    MatrixFile: TextFile;
begin
    ISize := 0;
    JSize := 0;
    IsCorrect := true;
    AssignFile(MatrixFile, Path);
    Reset(MatrixFile);
    while not(SeekEof(MatrixFile)) and IsCorrect do
    begin
        inc(ISize);
        while not(SeekEoln(MatrixFile)) and IsCorrect do
        begin
            try
                Read(MatrixFile, Num);
            except
                IsCorrect := false;
            end;
            inc(JSize);
        end;
        Readln(MatrixFile);
        if (JSize <> Order) then
            IsCorrect := false;
        JSize := 0;
    end;
    if ISize <> Order then
        IsCorrect := false;
    CloseFile(MatrixFile);
    result := IsCorrect;
end;

function FilePath(Order: Integer): String;
var
    Path: String;
    IsCorrect: Boolean;
begin
    repeat
        Writeln('Введите абсолютный путь к файлу ');
        Readln(Path);
        IsCorrect := false;
        if FileExists(Path) then
        begin
            if IsFileCorrect(Path, Order) then
                IsCorrect := true
            else
                Writeln('Данные в файле некорректны');
        end
        else
            Writeln('Файл не найден');

    until IsCorrect;
    result := Path;
end;

function InputOrder(): Integer;
var
    Order: Integer;
    IsCorrect: Boolean;
begin
    repeat
        Writeln('Введите порядок матрицы: ');
        IsCorrect := true;
        try
            Readln(Order)
        except
            IsCorrect := false;
            Writeln('Порядок матрицы должен быть числом')
        end;
    until IsCorrect;
    result := Order;
end;

function FileToMatrix(var MainMatrix:Matrix; Order: Integer; Path: String): Matrix;
var
    Ret: Matrix;
    I, J: Integer;
    MatrixFile: TextFile;
begin
    SetLength(Ret, Order, Order);
    AssignFile(MatrixFile, Path);
    Reset(MatrixFile);
    for I := 0 to Order do
    begin
        for J := 0 to Order do
        Read(MatrixFile, MainMatrix[I, J]);
        Readln(MatrixFile);
    end;
    CloseFile(MatrixFile);
    result := MainMatrix;
end;

function Output(): String;
var
    Patho: String;
    IsCorrect: Boolean;
begin
    IsCorrect := false;
    repeat
        Writeln('Введите директорию, в которую хотите сохранить матрицу');
        Readln(Patho);
        if DirectoryExists(Patho) then
            IsCorrect := true
        else
            Writeln('Такой директории не существует.Попробуйте ещё раз');
    until IsCorrect;
    Result := Patho;
end;

procedure ConditionToFile(MainMatrix: Matrix; Order: Integer; zero: array of Integer);
var
    I, J: Integer;
    OutputFile: TextFile;
    Directory: String;
begin
    Directory := Output();
    AssignFile(OutputFile, Directory + '\output.txt');
    Rewrite(OutputFile);

    for I := 0 to High(Zero) do
    begin
        Zero[I]:=1;
        Write(OutputFile, Zero[I]:6);
        Writeln(OutputFile);
    end;

    for I := 0 to High(MainMatrix) do
    begin
        for J := 0 to High(MainMatrix) do
            Write(OutputFile, MainMatrix[I, J]:6);
            Writeln(OutputFile);
    end;

        for I := 0 to High(Zero) do
    begin
        Zero[I]:=1;
        Write(OutputFile, Zero[I]:6);
        Writeln(OutputFile);
    end;

    Writeln('Матрица сохранена по указанному пути');
    CloseFile(OutputFile);
end;

procedure PrintMatrix(MainMatrix: Matrix);
var
    I, J: Integer;
begin
    for I := 0 to High(MainMatrix) do
    begin
        for J := 0 to High(MainMatrix) do
            Write(MainMatrix[I, J]:6);
            Writeln;
    end;
end;

procedure Condition(var MainMatrix: Matrix; Order: Integer; zero: array of Integer);
var
I, J:Integer;
begin
    for I := 0 to High(Zero) do
    begin
        Zero[I]:=1;
        Write(Zero[I]:6);
        Writeln;
    end;

    for I := 0 to High(MainMatrix) do
    begin
        for J := 0 to High(MainMatrix) do
            Write(MainMatrix[I, J]:6);
            Writeln;
    end;

    for I := 0 to High(Zero) do
    begin
    Zero[I]:=1;
    Write(Zero[I]:6);
    Writeln;
    end;

end;

begin
    Order := InputOrder();
    Path := FilePath(Order);
    MainMatrix := FileToMatrix(MainMatrix, Order, Path);
    PrintMatrix(MainMatrix);
    Condition(MainMatrix, Order, Zero);
    ConditionToFile(MainMatrix, Order, Zero);
    Readln;
end.
create new paste  /  syntax languages  /  archive  /  faq  /  tools  /  night mode  /  api  /  scraping api
privacy statement  /  cookies policy  /  terms of serviceupdated  /  security disclosure  /  dmca  /  report abuse  /  contact
```

После ввода пути к файлу (матрице) программа вылетает без ошибок. Даже не знаю в чём проблема. Пожалуйста, помогите!

Comment: Оберните в try except

Comment: Try
    Ваш основной код 
 
  except
    on E : Exception do
      ShowMessage(E.ClassName+' поднята ошибка, с сообщением : '+E.Message);
  end;

Answer (score 2):

Выход за пределы массива, последний индекс `Order-1`

Если включить опцию компилятор `range checking`, он бы предостерёг

```
SetLength(Ret, Order, Order);
...
 for I := 0 to Order do
  begin
    for J := 0 to Order do
    Read(MatrixFile, MainMatrix[I, J]);
```